# Is the preimage of a Hopf subalgebra a Hopf subalgebra?

Tags: hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, noncommutative-geometry

The following must be simple, but I have no intuition here, so excuse me.

Let $F$ and $G$ be [Hopf algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra) over a field $k$ (in the usual sence, i.e. Hopf algebras in the category of vector spaces over $k$). Let
$$
\varphi:F\to G
$$
be a morphism of Hopf algebras (i.e. $\varphi$ preserves multiplication, comultiplication, unit, counit and antipode), and
$$
H\subseteq G
$$
a Hopf subalgebra in $G$ (i.e. $H$ is a Hopf algebra with respect to the multiplication, comultiplication, unit, counit and antipode induced from $G$).

Question:

> Is it true that the preimage of $H$,
> $$
> \varphi^{-1}(H)=\{x\in F:\ \varphi(x)\in H\}
> $$
> is a Hopf subalgebra in $F$?

I asked this also at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453436/is-the-preimage-of-a-hopf-subalgebra-a-hopf-subalgebra).